# Show/Hide a div conditionally

Tags: jquery

How to show this div in the body if the URL contains `#people` substring

**The URL**

```
www.example.com/user=?232343_ads234324#people
```

**The div**

```
<div id="div1" class="seperate"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
  var url = document.location.toString();

  if (url.match('#people')) {
  $('#div1').show();
  }
  else {
  $('#div1').hide();
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `toggle()`, if the URL consists of `#people`, `#div1` is show, hide otherwise.

```
$('#div1').toggle(window.location.href.indexOf('#people') > -1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
if(window.location.hash != "#people") {
    $("#div1").hide();
}
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Why do you say that? My answer is a perfect solution for his question.

Comment: Oh, sorry. The comment was auto-generated by the review system, I didn't pay attention on it. I actually voted that this answer *should be a comment* because it's basically just a short code-snippet without any explanation (code-only answers are [discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148272/is-there-any-benefit-to-allowing-code-only-answers-while-blocking-code-only-ques)), although I might agree that it's OK in this case, because it's really simple.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the element is hidden at the beginning:

```
if (window.location.hash === "#people") {
    $("#div1").show();
}
```

But if you don't know the state, according to [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/toggle/#toggle-display):

```
$("#div1").toggle(window.location.hash === "#people");
```

If you want also show and hide this `div` with other hashes like `#allThePeople` I recommend:

```
$("#div1").toggle(new RegExp("people", 'i').test(window.location.hash));
// element.visibility (if you can find 'People' in current page URL)
```